Athena showing result but as empty rows
Every thing was working fine then i was notice May 24 result was fine but after that date data is missing then delete the old data and June-6-6 data was empty up querying but seeing that data exist in logs even i can download the logs and data in files but not on athena
Query: select * from alb_logs;


There isn't enough information here for anyone to help you.   What is the table DDL, did something change with s3 where data is stored, it was working and now it is not so what changed?

What happens if you select * from alb_logs?

Issue were in the data dont know how but created table with different columns it worked

For posterity, I've seen several people complain about the same issue, that happened exactly on that particular day: 24th of May 2024. Affected me as well. Dropping and re-creating the table helped.
